# Jquery validate вызывает зависание браузера

Tags: jquery, валидация

На сайте используется jquery v1.11.2 и jquery validate v1.14.0 . Обычная форма заказа товара

```html
<form action="/order.php" method="POST" class="b-order__form" id="order-form" novalidate="novalidate">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="b-order__form-label"><label for="fio"><span class="required-field">*</span>Контактное лицо</label></td>
    <td><input id="fio" name="fio" type="text" vk_1ae48="subscribed" aria-required="true" class="error" aria-invalid="true"><label id="fio-error" class="error" for="fio">Это поле необходимо заполнить.</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="b-order__form-label"><label for="phone"><span class="required-field">*</span>Номера телефонов</label></td>
    <td><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" vk_1ae48="subscribed" aria-required="true" class="error"><label id="phone-error" class="error" for="phone">Это поле необходимо заполнить.</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="b-order__form-label"><label for="email"><span class="required-field">*</span>E-mail</label></td>
    <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" vk_1ae48="subscribed" aria-required="true" class="error"><label id="email-error" class="error" for="email">Это поле необходимо заполнить.</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="b-order__form-label"><label for="address">Адрес доставки</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="address" name="address"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="b-order__form-label"><label for="comment">Примечание</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="b-order__form-submit">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Условия поставки принимаю. Оформить заказ!">
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>   
</form>
```

настроена валидация для трёх первых полей:

```js
 //Оформление заказа, валидация
 $('#order-form').validate({
  rules:{
   fio:{
    required:true,
    minlength:5
   },
 
   phone:{
    required:true,
    minlength:5
   },
   
   email:{
    required:true,
    email:true
   } 
  },
 });
```

небольшой ajax при отправке, перед которым проверяется валидность введённых данных.

```js
    //Оформление заказа, отправка формы
 $('#order-form').submit(function(){
      
    
      if($(this).valid()){
        //тут пошла ajax отправка данных
      
      
    });
```

Если ничего не заполнить и нажать отправить, браузер в 95% случаев виснет. А в консоля получаю такую ошибку: **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.** ( скриншот: http://joxi.ru/82QVa6LS1RXdVA ).

Т.к. файлы как jquery так и jquery.validate - обфусцированы, понять где возникает ошибка и что приводит к зависанию понять не могу. Может кто-то сталкивался подскажите, где искать проблему.